# ListView + Current row + ImageButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, imagebutton

I have a MSSQL table named "Account" which stores account info:

AccountID
SupplierID
AccountNumber
AccountDate
AccountFileName (name of pdf file)
AccountFileData (contents of PDF file, varbinary(max))

I also have a ListView (bound to table "Account" via DataSource) that displays Account info and a ImageButton inside ItemTemplate.
When I click ImageButton inside a row of ListView I want to open according PDF file.

Does anybody have an idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be simple. Configure your image button in the item template and give it a CommandName and CommandArgument (bound to the ID):

```
 ...
 <ItemTemplate>
     ...
     <asp:ImageButton runat="server" id="foobar" CommandName="DownloadPDF" CommandArgument='"<%# Eval( "AccountID" ) #>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Then, add the `OnItemCommand` to your ListView:

```
 <asp:ListView .... OnItemCommand="TheListView_ItemCommand"
```

and implement it to catch the `DownloadPDF` notification from the child control (the ImageButton):

```
    protected void TheListView_ItemCommand( object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e )
    {
        switch ( e.CommandName )
        {
            case "DownloadPDF":

                string accountID = e.CommandArgument;

                // now create the PDF and send it back to the client

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The solution is simple indeed!

Comment: Okay, I accepted your answer. Sorry but I can't vote for it because my reputation is low yet.